# Callback with geocoder.geocode

Tags: javascript

I have some issue with the callback inside `geocoder.geocode`.

```
var tri = new Array();
for (var j = 1; j < taille; j++) {
    where = getBoutique[j].adresse + ", " + getBoutique[j].ville;
    boutiqueProche(lat, lon, where, function (distanceO) {
        //window.localStorage.setItem("distance", distance);
        console.log(distanceO);
        tri.push(distanceO);
        //return distance;
        //console.log("Nous somme dans "+localStorage.getItem("distance"));
    });
    console.log("Inside " + tri);
}

function boutiqueProche(cLat, cLong, where, callback) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var currentPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(cLat, cLong); // On récupère nos info
    var recup = getBoutique.length;
    var distance;
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': where
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var laBoutique = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng());
            distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(currentPosition, laBoutique);
            recup = distance / 1000;
            callback(recup);
        } else {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    boutiqueProche(cLat, cLong, where, callback); // rappel fonction avec meme param
                }, 200);
            } else { /*Faire quelque chose */ }
        }
    });
}
```

I want to fill the array `tri` with the data from `recup` variable. But when I fill `tri`, nothing happens. It is empty.

What is the problem?

Comment: You are calling `console.log("Inside " + tri);` outside of the callback, i.e. before any element was added to the array. Making the geocoding request takes time and the `for` loop most likely finished before the first response was even received. Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/218196) to get an idea about the differences between synchronous and asynchronous code.

Comment: I read everything, understand the main problem but i don't know how to solve it...

Comment: You have to keep track of each call you make to `boutiqueProche` and execute a function once *all* responses have been received. The cleanest way to do this would be to use promises, such as implemented by when.js: https://github.com/cujojs/when.

Comment: where should i put promise().done();